# MongoDB query aggregation results with projection and GroupBy params

Tags: mongodb, group-by, concatenation

I am having three documents in a collection

**Example:**

All documents include these fields:

`Cid, AppName, imageHits (int), counter (int), imageNames (String)`

and I want to use `$group` on `Cid` and `AppName` and also I am doing the `$sum` operation on `counter (int)` and `imageHits (int)`. Till here I am getting the results as expected.

```
{ "_id" : { "cust_id" : "4" , "app" : "flipkart"} , "imageHits" : 10 , "counter" : 6}
{ "_id" : { "cust_id" : "1" , "app" : "gmail"} , "imageHits" : 1 , "counter" : 5}
```

My aggregation query:

```
BasicDBObject groupquery = new BasicDBObject(); 
BasicDBObject filter = new BasicDBObject("_id",new BasicDBObject("cust_id","$cid").append("app","$an"));
filter.append("imageHits",n‌​ew BasicDBObject("$sum","$ph"));
filter.append("counter",new BasicDBObject("$sum","$pg"));
groupquery.put("$group",filter); 
DBObject sortFields = new BasicDBObject("an", -1); 
DBObject sort=new BasicDBObject("$sort",sortFields); 
AggregationOutput aggregate=table.aggregate(matchQuery,sort,projection,groupquery);
Iterable<DBObje‌​ct> results=aggregate.results();
for (DBObject dbObject:results1{System.out.(dbObject);}
```

Now I need the `$concate` for `imageNames (String)` where `$group` should be same.

Comment: Can you show us a sample document and the expected output?

Comment: please provide your aggregation query.

Comment: BasicDBObject groupquery = new BasicDBObject();
BasicDBObject filter = new BasicDBObject("_id",new BasicDBObject("cust_id","$cid").append("app","$an"));filter.append("imageHits",new BasicDBObject("$sum","$ph"));filter.append("counter",new BasicDBObject("$sum","$pg"));groupquery.put("$group",filter);
DBObject sortFields = new BasicDBObject("an", -1);
DBObject sort=new BasicDBObject("$sort",sortFields);
AggregationOutput aggregate=table.aggregate(matchQuery,sort,projection,groupquery);Iterable<DBObject> results=aggregate.results();for (DBObject dbObject:results1{System.out.(dbObject);}

Comment: I got the answer for it

Comment: what we have to to is we have to use   object.append("imageNames",new BasicDBObject("$push","$imageNames"));  with groupBy operation to get the array of image names for perticular document